# Trigger VB.NET event when link in HTML is clicked

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a nice HTML document which I am successfully displaying within a `WebBrowser` control in VB.NET.  However, now what I want to do is to have my VB.NET code react, in some way, when a hyperlink in the HTML document is clicked.  How can I have the VB.NET code detect when a link, or some other HTML element, is clicked?  Is it possible for the html page to trigger an event in VB.NET?  If so how can I do that?

Comment: Have you at least   [searched](http://tinyurl.com/op6yhd4) before you've posted this poor question? Please read  [this](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Comment: You want to programatically click the element on the HTML page via VB code, or you want to have your VB code detect when the user clicks on the element in the HTML page?

Comment: Steven I was currious towards the second I know that the first is possible. The reason is because I have a sweet HTML code with links and what but I need some things done with vb.net. pending on what the user clicks in the html.

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT Ok, I edited your question to make your intention more clear.  Hopefully that will stop it from receiving any more close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect when the user clicks on a hyperlink, you can do so by handling the `WebBrowser` control's `Navigating` event.  If you want to know when a button in the HTML page is clicked, you can do so by handling the `Click` event of the button's `HtmlElement` object.